# How do I use generator objects in spaCy?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy

First experience with NLP here. I have about a half million tweets. I'm trying to use spacy to remove stop words, lemmatize, etc. and then pass the processed text to a classification model. Because of the size of the data I need multiprocessing to do this in reasonable speed, but can't figure out what to do with the generator object once I have it.

Here I load spacy and pass the data through the standard pipeline:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en')

tweets = ['This is a dummy tweet for stack overflow',
         'What do we do with generator objects?']
spacy_tweets = []
for tweet in tweets:
    doc_tweet = nlp.pipe(tweet, batch_size = 10, n_threads = 3)
    spacy_tweets.append(doc_tweet)
```

Now I'd like to take the Doc objects spaCy creates and then process the text with something like this:

```
def spacy_tokenizer(tweet):
    tweet = [tok.lemma_.lower().strip() if tok.lemma_ != "-PRON-" else tok.lower_ for tok in tweet]
    tweet = [tok for tok in tweet if (tok not in stopwords and tok not in punctuations)] 
    return tweet
```

But this doesn't work because spaCy returns generator objects when using the .pipe() method. So when I do this:

```
for tweet in spacy_tweets:
    print(tweet)
```

It prints the generator. Okay, I get that. But when I do this:

```
for tweet in spacy_tweets[0]:
    print(tweet)
```

I would expect it to print the Doc object or the text of the tweet in the generator but it doesn't do that. Instead it prints each character our individually.

Am I approaching this wrong or is there something I need to do in order to retrieve the Doc objects from the generator objects so I can use the spaCy attributes for lemmatizing etc.?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Doc object"? To me it seems you either want to access individual fields of the object, or retrieve the text only, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are using wrongly the nlp.pipe command.

nlp.pipe is for parallelization which means that it processes simultaneously tweets. So, instead of giving to nlp.pipe command a single tweet as an argument, you should pass the tweets list.

The following code seems to achieve your goal:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')

tweets = ['This is a dummy tweet for stack overflow',
         'What do we do with generator objects?']
spacy_tweets = nlp.pipe(tweets, batch_size = 10, n_threads = 3)

for tweet in spacy_tweets:
    for token in tweet:
        print(token.text, token.pos_)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This worked! So if I'm understanding what's happening correctly, when I pass individual text samples to nlp.pipe() it's returning a generator object for each text, and when I pass that generator through a loop it prints each character. When I past a list of text samples to nlp.pipe() it results in a single generator object containing all of the text and when I loop it, it prints each token.

Seems obvious now that I'm typing it out. Thanks for your help!